# Zepto load content into a div, animation and back

Tags: cordova, jqtouch, zepto

I discovered zepto frameworks, i read all the example available but i not sure to uderstand how to do this:

i need to load a content into a div, after load it move with an animation to this div for display it and display in the toolbar the back button. some things are available in the annexed examples but i do not understand how to go back with the view.

if it necessary loading again the previus content or it's alredy cached.

i'll trying to do an app for ipad with phonegab as bridge at the begin i tried with jqtouch that managed this easly but it's very slow on ipad when embed into phonegap.

There is a way insted to use zepto with jqtouch?

Help and suggestion ar very appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jquery Mobile

http://jquerymobile.com/

It will give you better performance, and will have an easy learning curve, take a look at this tutorial on integrating Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Comment: Thank for your answer, i'm searching for a compact framework for create a balance with native code and js code.

Comment: Probably zepto is the best option so far, i haven't found any other option with the size and the capabilities of Zepto so far.